# How to use OnTouchListener to switch fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

For my main activity I have aproxximately 12 fragments that I want to switch between. For this first one I'm trying to use an OnTouchListener for the whole screen to switch the view. I'm currently trying to create a interface so that when I click the screen in this fragment the main activity will implement code to switch to a different view. this is what I have so far:

```
public class suggestedfriends extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search,
            container, false);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
      }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener{
        public void switchfirstscreen();
    }
}
```

Help on this simplest fragment is greatly appreciated as it will help me implement code for the remaining eleven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a method that recieves a Fragment instance as a paramenter and make the fragment transaction.

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    if(null != fragment){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

So in your onTouch method call you do something like:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeFragment(new MyFragment);
            return true;
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Also read this: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
Best Regards.

Comment: ok so quick comment I get how this would work, but how would I set the main activities view to this first one. and also would this change the mainlayout's xml file in anyway. this is my mainlayout's xml as you can see I have set the other fragment's visibility to zero, and I intend for each fragment to take up the whole screen.

Comment: <fragment class="com.example.demoww.suggestedfriend"
     android:id="@+id/suggestedfriendLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    
    <fragment class="com.example.demoww.profile"
     android:id="@+id/ProfileLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:visibility="gone"/>

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work. Because changeFragment() doesn't return the Fragment view, you'll get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id ...for fragment MyFragment.